# What is the best way to set nvd3 x domain range for dynamically changing time?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I am looking for the best way to set nvd3 chart x domain to represent given period of time in real time line chart - for example last hour. 
In other words - I am adding new data (y is numeric value, x is timestamp) every second and I want x axis to show last hour of time. Currently I am updating forceX with every data update - it works, but seems very ineffective.

```
var startDate = (new Date()).getTime();
startDate = startDate-3600000;
options.chart.forceX = [startDate,new Date()];
data[0].values.push({x: new Date(), y: newValue});
api.update();
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

In D3 JS ; code like below can be used to update the axis based on the change on scale values,

```
 // Update scale with new values
  var xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([newMinDate, newMaxDate])   
        .range([0,width]);

   // Update the Axis new scale
   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom");

  // select svg axis node and update the view
  svg.selectAll("g.x-axis").call(xAxis)
```

Comment: It seems very similar to what I am doing with nvd3 (forceX), but it causes whole chart (both axis) redraw every data update with flickering.I am wondering if there is a faster method?

Comment: To avoid flickering you can use d3  animations,  for example **axis .transition().duration(500).ease("linear")**, but which will not improve performance.

Comment: OK, I managed to get what I needed using simple trick:
1. Initialize XDomain for specific period of time:

`XDomain: [new Date()- chartPeriod,new Date()]`

2. Check if oldest date is not too old for the period I am interested in, and removing it:

`if (data[0].values[0].x.getTime () < startDate)
                        {
       
                            data[0].values.shift();
                        }`